# Push to Docker Hub fails with "500 Internal Server Error"

Tags: docker

Beginning Docker user, running Docker 1.8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 (on Vagrant/VirtualBox). Trying to push a Docker image to Docker Hub with the following command:

```
sudo docker push myaccountname/someimage:latest
```

I get the following output:

```
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/myaccountname/someimage] (len: 1)
7d04353ac85e: Pushing [==================================================>] 4.516 kB/4.516 kB
Received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error
```

I've checked the Docker Daemon log at /var/log/upstart/docker.log, but it contains no error message, merely says:

```
INFO[0772] POST /v1.20/images/myaccountname/someimage/push?tag=latest
```

Any ideas on this would be much appreciated.

UPDATE:
When trying again the next day, this suddenly worked as expected. Must have been some temporary problem with Docker Hub.

Comment: Is it possible that it's a bug? https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15833

Answer (score 1):

i have experienced same issue couple of times. 
try re-push once or more than once (depends on luck) may push successfully.
not sure whether it relates to stability of docker hub infrastructure.